# Save/load sympy lambdifed expressions

Tags: python, lambda, sympy

Imagine the following three step process:

- I use sympy to build a large and somewhat complicated expression (this process costs a lot of time).
- That expression is then converted into a lambda function using `sympy.lambdify` (also slow).
- Said function is then evaluated (fast)

Ideally, steps 1 and 2 are only done once, while step 3 will be evaluated multiple times. Unfortunately the evaluations of step 3 are spread out over time (and different python sessions!)

I'm searching for a way to save the "lambdified" expression to disk, so that I can load and use them at a later point. Unfortunately pickle does not support lambda functions. Also my lambda function uses numpy.

I could of course create a matching function by hand and use that, but that seems inefficient and error-prone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use "dill", as described here

[How to serialize sympy lambdified function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314517/how-to-serialize-sympy-lambdified-function)

and

[How to use dill to serialize a class definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613543/how-to-use-dill-to-serialize-a-class-definition)

You have to import dill and set the variable 'recursive' to the value "True".

```
import dill
dill.settings['recurse'] = True
```

Lets say f is your lambdified function. You can dump it to disk using the following.

```
dill.dump(f, open("myfile", "wb"))
```

Afterwards you can load the function with the following line. This can be also done from another python script.

```
f_new=dill.load(open("myfile", "rb"))
```

Comment: I edited my answer according to  G. Bernstein' s comment to be compatible with python 3

Answer (score 4):

The above works well.
In my case with Python 3.6, I needed to explicitly indicate that the saved and loaded files were binary. So modified the code above to:

`dill.dump(f, open("myfile", "wb"))`

and for reading:

`f_new=dill.load(open("myfile", "rb"))`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to store the lambdified function as Python code.
I realized that using `pickle` or `dill` can sometimes be a security risk and wanted to find a different solution to this problem.
Once you have lambdified the sympy expression into the function `func`, you can use

```py
import inspect
func_code = inspect.getsource(func)
```

to get the generated function as a string. This string will look like the following:

```py
def _lambdifygenerated(function arguments...):
    return ...
```

I highly suggest to look at the generated code and modify the string.
You will have to fix the imports (like numpy functions) manually, and you could change the function name by just using [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace).

Once you have executable code, you can save it as a .py file:

```py
with open("path/to/file.py", "w") as file:
    file.write(func_code)
```

The reason this works better than using [sympy's printing utilities](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/printing.html) (like `sympy.printing.numpy.NumpyPrinter`) is that [lambdify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify) has a lot more options for example the common subexpressions substitution, which can help speeding up the evaluation of large expressions.