# How to serialize sympy lambdified function?

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, pickle, sympy

The title says it all. Is there any way to serialize a function generated by sympy.lambdify?:

```
import sympy as sym
import pickle
import dill
a, b = sym.symbols("a, b")
expr = sym.sin(a) + sym.cos(b)
lambdified_expr = sym.lambdify((a, b), expr, modules="numpy")
pickle.dumps(lambdified_expr) # won't work
dill.dumps(lambdified_expr) # won't work either
```

... The reason I want to do this is because my code generates so many lambdified functions but I found it takes too long every time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You actually *can* use `dill` to pickle it.  The most recent versions of `dill` (e.g. on github) has "settings" that allow variants of how the pickle is constructed on `dump`.  Yes, the default settings for `dill` fail on this object, but not if you use the setting that recursively traces global references (i.e. `recurse = True`).  This setting is similar to what `cloudpickle` gives you by default.

```
>>> import sympy as sym
>>> import pickle
>>> import dill
>>> a, b = symbols("a, b")
>>> a, b = sym.symbols("a, b")
>>> expr = sym.sin(a) + sym.cos(b)
>>> lambdified_expr = sym.lambdify((a, b), expr, modules="numpy")
>>> 
>>> dill.settings
{'recurse': False, 'byref': False, 'protocol': 2, 'fmode': 0}
>>> dill.settings['recurse'] = True
>>> dill.dumps(lambdified_expr)
'\x80\x02cdill.dill\n_create_function\nq\x00(cdill.dill\n_unmarshal\nq\x01U\x83c\x02\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00C \x00\x00s\x14\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00|\x00\x00\x83\x01\x00t\x01\x00|\x01\x00\x83\x01\x00\x17S(\x01\x00\x00\x00N(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x03\x00\x00\x00sint\x03\x00\x00\x00cos(\x02\x00\x00\x00t\x01\x00\x00\x00at\x01\x00\x00\x00b(\x00\x00\x00\x00(\x00\x00\x00\x00s\x08\x00\x00\x00<string>t\x08\x00\x00\x00<lambda>\x01\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x02\x85q\x03Rq\x04}q\x05(U\x03cosq\x06cnumpy.core.umath\ncos\nq\x07U\x03sinq\x08cnumpy.core.umath\nsin\nq\tuU\x08<lambda>q\nNN}q\x0btq\x0cRq\r.'
```

P.S. I'm the `dill` author, so I'd know.

Comment: why recurse=True is not a default option?

Comment: Because `dill` can serialize a broad range of objects, and `recurse=False` provides the broadest range of coverage.  If you use `recurse=True`, it works really well for certain objects, but breaks serialization for a number of cases.  If (or when) I resolve the cases it breaks, then it will become the default.  Until then, the best choice is to *not* remove default functionality, but provide new functionality via a setting. See: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/105

Comment: @MikeMcKerns I have one caveat, for reasonably large lambadified functions I get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

Comment: @JoshAlbert: I expect you are seeing a specific case of pickling with lambdas.  `dill` should pickle the lambda, regardless of the size of the function. If you can demonstrate a specific case of failure, please submit a question on SO, or a ticket on dill's github page.

Comment: Apparently, `dill.dump` has a `recurse` argument: `Signature: dill.dump(obj, file, protocol=None, byref=None, fmode=None, recurse=None)`. Is this the same option you can set globally in the snippet you provided? So, instead of using `dill.settings['recurse'] = True` could I just use `dill.dump(..., recurse=True)`?

Comment: @Spiros: That's correct, you can set it on a per-call basis.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns: thanks. When deserializing a rather complex expression I previously dumped with `dill`, I got this error message: `TypeError: argument is not an mpz`. Is this something known? Dill works with simple expressions for me, but complex expressions trigger this problem.

Comment: @Spiros: That is not a `dill` error.  You can turn on `dill.detect.trace(True)` and see where it comes from.  I'd google a bit to see which package throws that error.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed - pickle, cPickle, and even dill fail on this example with default settings.

But cloudpickle does not fail!

```
pip install cloudpickle
```

or

https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle

```
import sympy as sym
from cloudpickle import dumps, loads
a, b = sym.symbols("a, b")
expr = sym.sin(a) + sym.cos(b)
lambdified_expr = sym.lambdify((a, b), expr, modules="numpy")
var=dumps(lambdified_expr)
a1=lambdified_expr(10,10)
del lambdified_expr
lambdified_expr=loads(var)
a2=lambdified_expr(10,10)
a1==a2  # True
```