# How to use sympy codegen with expressions that contain implemented functions

Tags: python, sympy, codegen

Im trying to compile an expression that contains an UndefinedFunction which has an implementation provided. (Alternatively: an expression which contains a Symbol which represents a call to an external numerical function)

Is there a way to do this? Either with autowrap or codegen or perhaps with some manual editing of the generated files?

The following naive example does not work:

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
from sympy.abc import *
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import implemented_function
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import autowrap, ufuncify

def g_implementation(a):
    """represents some numerical function"""
    return a*5

# sympy wrapper around the above function
g = implemented_function('g', g_implementation)

# some random expression using the above function
e = (x+g(a))**2+100

# try to compile said expression
f = autowrap(e, backend='cython')
# fails with "undefined reference to `g'"
```

**EDIT:**

I have several large Sympy expressions

The expressions are generated automatically (via differentiation and such)

The expressions contain some "implemented UndefinedFunctions" that call some    numerical functions (i.e. NOT Sympy expressions)

The final script/program that has to evaluate the expressions for some input    will be called quite often. That means that evaluating the expression in Sympy (via evalf) is definitely not feasible. Even compiling just in time (lambdify, autowrap, ufuncify, numba.jit) produces too much of an overhead.

Basically I want to create a binary python extension for those expressions without having to implement them by hand in C, which I consider too error prone.

OS is Windows 7 64bit

Comment: Hi PeterE, I am not sure if you need sympy or not? If not you can use directly cython, can you not?

Comment: @andi My actual expressions are fairly long and convoluted. I create them by automated differentiation (among other things) with Sympy. Also there are quite a lot of them. Implementing them by hand is exactly what I'm trying to avoid. ;)

Comment: I believe that ;). I know it is not exactly on topic, but also have a look at lamdify, which makes a numerical lamda-function from a sympy-expression expression.

Comment: @andi Hm, I also want to avoid having to recreate the "binary" (for my purposes that also includes lambda expressions) on each execution. I hope to compile into a reusable dll/pyd.

Comment: Ok, then your question is not perfectly clear to me. What do you have given?

Comment: Do you use windows or linux?

Comment: Ok, I still do not know what your numerical function does? If you have sympy expressions, I can show you how to autowrap them to get executable cython functions. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @andi The point is, that that numerical function should be called by the generated code when needed. I don't think the actual implementation is relevant here (It is some specialized numerical interpolation/conversion of the input argument). I have successfully used autowrap to produce compiled functions from expressions that do NOT contain (implemented) UndefinedFunctions. I assume, that, to get persistent binaries I will have to use the lower-level codegen instead of the more easy to use autowrap, but that assumes that I can solve the problem with the UndefinedFunctions somehow.

Comment: It looks like `autowrap` takes an optional `helpers` argument which may do what you need.  http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/autowrap.html#sympy.utilities.autowrap.autowrap

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [this answer about serialization of SymPy lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314517/how-to-serialize-sympy-lambdified-function) (generated by lambdify).

It's not exactly what you asked but may alleviate your problem with startup performance. Then lambdify-ied functions will mostly count only execution time.

You may also take a look at [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/). It has nice integration with SymPy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this could do the trick, I hope, if not let me know and I'll try again.

I compare a compiled version of an expression using `Cython` against the `lambdified` expression.

```
from sympy.utilities.autowrap import autowrap
from sympy import symbols, lambdify

def wraping(expression):
    return autowrap(expression, backend='cython')

def lamFunc(expression, x, y):
    return lambdify([x,y], expr)

x, y = symbols('x y')
expr = ((x - y)**(25)).expand()
print expr


binary_callable = wraping(expr)
print binary_callable(1, 2)

lamb = lamFunc(expr, x, y)
print lamb(1,2)
```

which outputs:

```
x**25 - 25*x**24*y + 300*x**23*y**2 - 2300*x**22*y**3 + 12650*x**21*y**4 - 53130*x**20*y**5 + 177100*x**19*y**6 - 480700*x**18*y**7 + 1081575*x**17*y**8 - 2042975*x**16*y**9 + 3268760*x**15*y**10 - 4457400*x**14*y**11 + 5200300*x**13*y**12 - 5200300*x**12*y**13 + 4457400*x**11*y**14 - 3268760*x**10*y**15 + 2042975*x**9*y**16 - 1081575*x**8*y**17 + 480700*x**7*y**18 - 177100*x**6*y**19 + 53130*x**5*y**20 - 12650*x**4*y**21 + 2300*x**3*y**22 - 300*x**2*y**23 + 25*x*y**24 - y**25

-1.0
-1
```

If I time the execution times the autowraped function is 10x faster (depending on the problem I have also observed cases where the factor was as little as two):

```
%timeit binary_callable(12, 21)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.87 µs per loop

%timeit lamb(12, 21)
100000  loops, best of 3: 28.7 µs per loop
```

So here `wraping(expr)` wraps your expression `expr` and returns a wrapped object `binary_callable`. This you can use at any time to do numerical evaluation.

**EDIT:** I have done this on Linux/Ubuntu and Windows OS, both seem to work fine!

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but you have missed the point. The expression I'm trying to compile contains not just sympy `Symbol`s but also sympy `UndefinedFunction`s. Just try running the code in my OP and see what happens.

Comment: Well, that is what I was afraif of. Sorry, but I really seem to miss the point then.

Comment: It would really make it a whole lot easier if you could specify in and output. UndefinedFunction doesen't really say much :(

Comment: `UndefinedFunction` is a sympy class (like `Symbol`) representing a function. It may or may not have a (numerical) implementation. In my case there is an implementation, that should be integrated when calling the compiled expression. I'm kind of afraid, that it is not possible to do that.

Comment: well, there are several methods to include numerical functions in expression from numpy like this: 

if you had a sympy expression: x + 2*y
and y would be a numerical function like:
def Y(y):
     return 2*y
that is doable. But I do not see it with autowrap.

Comment: @andi is right. This is currently not supported by autowrap.