# Python: Transfer a class method to another computer

Tags: python, dill

I have created an class that is used for analysising a specific type of data that I produce. I use this class on a local computer but occasionally there is too much data to work locally so I wanted to add an option to one of methods so that it can submit the job to a computer cluster. It mostly works except I am struggling to transfer a class method to the cluster.

My class looks like this

```
class Analysis():
    def __init__(self, INPUT_PARAMETERS ETC):
        self.data
        OTHER_STUFF...
    @staticmethod
    def staticMethod1(input1, input2):
        # PERFORM SOME KIND OF CALCULATION ON INPUT1 AND INPUT2 AND RETURN THE RESULT
        return output

    @staticmethod
    def staticMethod2(input1, input2):
        # PERFORM SOME KIND OF CALCULATION ON INPUT1 AND INPUT2 AND RETURN THE RESULT
        return output

    # MORE STATIC METHODS

    @staticmethod
    def staticMethodN(input1, input2):
        # PERFORM SOME KIND OF CALCULATION ON INPUT1 AND INPUT2 AND RETURN THE RESULT
        return output

    def createArray(self, function):
        # CREATE AN ARRAY BY APPLYING FUNCTION TO SELF.DATA
        return array
```

So the `createArray` method gets called and the user passes the static method that should be used to calculate the array. When I wanted the array in `createArray` to be created on the cluster I saved the static method (that was passed to the this method e.g. `staticMethod1`) into a `Pickle` file using `dill.dump`.  The `Pickle` file is then passed to the cluster but when I try to load the method from the `Pickle` file it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'analysis'` which is the module that the `Analysis` class can be found in.

Do I really need to recreate the whole class on the cluster just to use a static method? Can anyone suggest a elegant fix to this problem or suggest a better way of implementing this functionality? It needs to work with any static method. FYI, one of the static methods uses `from sklearn.metrics.cluster import adjusted_rand_score` just incase that may effect a solution using `dill`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the `dill` author.  `dill` is able to pass a class method to another computer, as seen below.

```
>$ python
Python 3.5.6 (default, Sep 20 2018, 12:15:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def bar(self, x):
...     return self.y + x
...   def __init__(self, y):
...     self.y = y
... 
>>> import dill
>>>          
>>> f = Foo(5)
>>>                  
>>> with open('foo.pkl', 'wb') as pkl:
...   dill.dump(f.bar, pkl)
... 
>>>
```

Then in a new session (or on another computer)...

```
>$ python
Python 3.5.6 (default, Sep 20 2018, 12:15:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import dill
>>> with open('foo.pkl', 'rb') as pkl:
...   b = dill.load(pkl)
... 
>>> b(4)
9
```

Without more specific code from you, it's hard to say why you aren't seeing this behavior... but `dill` does provide the ability to pass a class definition (or just a class method) to another computer.

This behavior is what enables code like `pathos` to pass the class method to another computer within a `ParallelPool` or a `ProcessPool` -- the latter is across processes, while the former can be across distributed resources.

```
dude>$ python
Python 3.5.6 (default, Sep 20 2018, 12:15:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> class Foo(object):
...   def bar(self, x):
...     return self.y + x
...   def __init__(self, y):
...     self.y = y
... 
>>> import pathos
>>> p = pathos.pools.ParallelPool()
>>> p.map(Foo(4).bar, [1,2,3])
[5, 6, 7]
>>> p.close(); p.join()
>>>
```

Comment: Also, see this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25613543/how-to-use-dill-to-serialize-a-class-definition/25623532#25623532